# Opera 11: Disable "suggestions" in search box

Tags: opera, privacy, autocomplete, privacy-protection, opera-11

After installing Opera 11 I want to disable Search Suggestions.

Right next to the address bar is a search box.  When I start typing anything into it, after a moment search suggestions appear.  So, this means that Opera sends my typed text to "Some Third-Party" before I ask to do it (before pressing the Enter key).

There must be a configuration variable with suggest service url, but I can find such a variable in the `about:config` hacking page.

How can I disable this "search suggestion / auto-completion" feature?

Comment: Obsolete? It's Opera 88.0.4412.xx right now, however the question remains. How to disable Opera showing suggestions etc.

Comment: "Use a prediction service to help complete searches and URLs typed in the address bar" doesn't stop Opera from showing e. g. links from Bookmarks.

Comment: Related: https://forums.opera.com/topic/42497/want-no-drop-down-box-suggestions-in-address-bar/18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Suggest URL is stored in `search.ini`](http://my.opera.com/Tamil/blog/google-search-suggestions-in-opera)

Comment: This stop sending to third patry, but not stop a menu dropdown

Comment: Link above is obsolete, pointing nowhere.

Answer (score 2):

In that `search.ini` file mentioned above, comment out the line that says "Suggest URL" by placing a semi-colon in front of it.

My line now looks like this:

```
;Suggest URL=http://clients1.google.com/complete/search?q={SearchTerm}&client=opera&hl=en
```

Answer (score 1):

Try typing this in Opera's address bar:

```
opera:config#UserPrefs|AutoDropdown
```

Then uncheck auto-dropdown, then scroll down and save. Restart Opera and let's see if it worked.

Comment: This does disable dropdown of address bar, not the search bar (

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked a while ago, but i think others will benefit from knowing that the search suggestions you are referring to is called the Start Bar. It is easily disabled in <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> > Toolbars > uncheck...

Comment: No. "Start bar" is uncheked. I asked about suggestions not for address bar (http://...) but for search bar (which has grey text Google)

Answer (score 0):

Attention:

```
opera:config#UserPrefs|AutoDropdown
```

(from the accepted answer by [osgx](https://superuser.com/users/15484/osgx)) only works, when you use english language, it doesn't work for me using german (there this feature is called "Vorhersageservice zur Vervollständigung von Suchanfragen und URLs bei der Eingabe in die Adressleiste verwenden").
Plus the link doesn't work anymore and forwards to the main page.

I know too that This has been asked a while ago, but I hope, others will benefit from this.

---

Of course, you can edit the `search.ini` by hand, but I found this Software:
[3866-opera-search-ini-editor](https://www.netzwelt.de/software-chooser/3866-opera-search-ini-editor.html)
(Click on "Download starten")